# Is this innerHTML hack "valid"?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

So let's say I have this `<div>` element:

```
...
<div id="me"></div>
...
```

Then I have a script like this:

```
var me = document.getElementById("me");

me.innerHTML = '<span color="#00F">Hello!';
```

Is this script a bad "hack" or not, why do I have to write/do I even have to write:

```
me.innerHTML = '<span color="#00F">Hello!</span>';
```

, with the ending `</span>` instead?

Comment: You *can* but you *shouldn't*. That is, if you care about the HTML standard.

Comment: @Alternatex Why can I when I shouldn't, I mean what did the people think who wrote the innerHTML method? Did they think "Oh let's make it as hard as it just possibly can be to debug! Great idea!"

Comment: In many cases browser be smart enough to recognize when the tag should be closed. However, this is not the case always. And browser engines works differently. You would't ask this question if you had a chance to develop for old IE browsers.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah I get it, but IE was kind of a bad example, no one uses it really

Comment: @Murplyx You can also write `delete 5;` in JavaScript which is a valid command but does nothing. Many ridiculous things are possible, it's up to you to not be fooled by language and specification quirks.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting html like `'<span color="#00F">Hello!';` is bad practice though the major browsers will automatically add the closing tag.

To always be consistent, wrap html with closing tag.

From the comment:

> Then why is it bad if the browser will automatically add the closing tag?

First of all you're forcing browser to do that which is time consuming and next not all browsers are supposed to work like that.

Comment: Then why is it bad if the browser will automatically add the closing tag?

Comment: Is this auto closing tag feature something new like in HTML5?

Comment: no, it's not self-closing :) self closing would like `<input />`

Comment: Not that kind of self closing, the innerHTML's self closing mechanism obviously.

Comment: That's not self-closing tag, you're just missing to close the tags i.e. just closing tag not self-closing tag.

Comment: Alright then if you don't understand from the very obvious context I made it easier for you by editing the content of that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Valid HTML is predictable, thus it's robust and reliable. HTML tag soup depends in the specific fixes applied by each browser, thus can lead to inconsistencies and hard to diagnose bugs.